# How can i apply primefaces tabview dynamic attribute to individual tabs

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

Is there any way to make certain tabs of tabview in primefaces are dynamic. As of now either all tabs are dynamic or all tabs are static.

Comment: You can enhance your question to be more clear: please edit your question to provide a [mcve]. Add an example tabview xhtml code that you tried out and describe expected vs observed behavior.

Comment: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/32

Comment: Use ui:repeat to add the dynamic tabs